# 2 FancyBox popups, overlay-flash class

Tags: fancybox

We are having 2 applications in the same page both of which use 1 fancybox each.The first application which is flex based loads a fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("a.overlay-flash").fancybox({ 
      'padding' : 0, 
      'width'   : 800, 
      'height'  : 450, 
    }); 
}); 

<a  id="hiddenclickermarketInfoPortlet" class="overlay-flash" href="<%=targetThemeURLStr%>" >Hidden Clicker</a>
```

But when we load our application and call our fancybox it seems the first fancybox gets loaded again.

So 2 questions are

1. Is there a way to close the original fancybox from our second application?
2. What or where is this overlay-flash class defined? I checked in the net and lot of people are using this class. (Note the first loaded application is flexbased and ours non-flex based)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have two FancyBoxes open and styled... it is meant to be unique and thus has IDs for all of the elements.

But, if you need to close FancyBox, use [the API](http://fancybox.net/api)

```
$.fancybox.close
```

Should you need to disable the overlay, just use the overlayShow option:

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
  overlayShow : false
});
```

or since it sounds like you might not have control over the options, add this to your css:

```
#fancybox-overlay { display: none !important; }
```

If you are still having problems, please share some of the markup and code you are using

---

If you need to apply a plugin to the content inside the fancybox, then do so using the `onComplete` callback

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
  overlayShow : false,
  onComplete:function(){
    $('#cboxContent').find('input').autocomplete();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi there thanks.That worked using $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
  overlayShow : false
});
Didnot use the css addtion option as the other fancybox was getting impacted also

Comment: Interestingly however the application that popups in the fancybox has a text box to enter some value to search.If we open this application using regular window.open then the autocomplete feature of the popedup application works. However if we open the application using fancybox then autocomplete feature doesnot work.(something like the autocomplete stuff you have in google).

Comment: Then maybe you need to use the `onComplete` callback... I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am trying out something based on the above lines you have suggested. Will reply back soon on this thread after the POC is completed in a day or so